# HTML inside JSP if() statement not working

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, if-statement

Thanks for the help.  It was and error with having variable equal b instead of b equals variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You should also read [how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any whitespace in there fouling things up?  Try `'<%= useranswer[0] %>'` (wrapped in single quotes) to check.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, no whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use  if (useranswer[0].equals("b")) instead. 
equals means the string are same.

But == means they are same object in memory.

Comment: did you post your exact code?  If you're getting a null pointer exception with that call, that probably means that `useranswer[0]` is null.

Comment: Always use const value first when you compare: `"b".equals(useranswer[0])` That'll prevent NullPointerExceptions.